# How to attach libraries to JAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

It works fine when compiling project, but after exporting it to a runnable `jar` and launching, it can't find external files and throws an error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt building a `fat jar` that includes all the jars. It contains a custom class loader to load the jars referenced externally by your project.

Try using http://fjep.sourceforge.net/ plugin to build a fat jar.

You can export a java project containing jars using the `File -> Export -> Other -> One Jar Exporter`.

[image]

The jar thus exported works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add external libraries to the `manifest.mf`:

```
Class-Path: . MyApp_lib/extlib.jar MyApp_lib/extlib2.jar ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep all required jars in the classpath to run your jar. Run your jar like :

`java -cp extlib/*  -jar yourjar.jar` OR `java -cp lib1.jar:lib2.jar:..  -jar yourjar.jar`

Comment: what if there are, like, hundreds of them? coz that's my case

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that while building the jar, you include all the used libraries(include everything from class path). This issue will happen when you refer a external jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a classpath variable in the jar's manifest file.

[JAR file classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)