# NoClassDefFoundError, in the same directory why the program can't find the jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

I write a Java program that read text from excel.So I import some jar like this: `poi-3.10-beta2-20130904.jar`, `poi-ooxml-3.10-beta2-20130904.jar`, etc., **I can run the program correctly in eclipse.But when  I package this program with maven to the directory(`C:\workspace2\change\bin`)**,

Then I run this program in command like this :

```
C:\workspace2\change\bin>java GenerateVar
```

it occurs this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell
    at GenerateVar.execute(GenerateVar.java:59)
    at GenerateVar.main(GenerateVar.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Show us how you are trying to run the program.  What command line are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you run it from eclipse in the console there's a command that could be used to run the project, you could copy/paste it from the console to your command line.

In the command `java GenerateVar` you didn't set `-cp` option. With this option the command line will look like

`java -cp poi-3.10-beta2-20130904.jar poi-ooxml-3.10-beta2-20130904.jar ... GenerateVar`

Assumed the libraries are in the current dir.

How to use maven plugins to add dependency to your project and build jar you can find [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040063/573032) answer if you want to modify `manifest.mf` manually.

Comment: can you tell me more details about this? please

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify classpath with all other jars/classes you use in your program.
E.g. [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

over, I change the way do what I want to do. I use the fat jar which is the eclipse plugin to package the program